# Trouble with setting a start point with pyparsing and nestedExpr

Tags: python, nested, pyparsing

Sorry for the newbie question but this problem has been driving me nuts and many hours of searching haven't found me a solution.

I have a router config input file which looks something like:

```
groups {
...some nested info...
}
some text....
system {
...some nested info...
}
chassis {
...some nested info...
}
```

Now using pyparsing and nestedExpr, I can parse the first part 'groups' and I get a set of lists within lists which are perfect, but I can't continue on to 'system' or 'chassis'.

Ideally, I'd like to start at 'chassis' and just get the list of lists from that section and nothing else.

Is there a way of getting pyparsing and nestedExpr to either do the whole file or start at a certain point?

My current code is pretty simple, ideally how do I get it to start from 'chassis':

```
from pyparsing import *    

with open('newfile.txt') as routerFile:
    test = routerFile.read()

    expr = Word(alphas) + nestedExpr('{','}')
    print expr.parseString(test)
```

Comment: Is `'chassis'` nested in `'system'`? or should that be a `'}'` after system's nested info?

Comment: Yep, Chassis and system are separate, now fixed, thanks for picking up on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options when you want to parse only selected bits of a larger text.

One is to use pyparsing's `SkipTo` class.

```
from pyparsing import Word, SkipTo

text = "AAA stuff I dont care about BBB more junk"

part1 = Word("A")
part2 = Word("B")
parser = part1 + SkipTo(part2) + part2

print(parser.parseString(text).asList())
```

prints

```
['AAA', 'stuff I dont care about ', 'BBB']
```

If you *really* don't want that intervening stuff, use `SkipTo(part2).suppress()`.

Another way to pick through text is to use scanString or searchString instead of parseString, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439662/skip-to-first-possibility-in-text-with-pyparsing/32443820#32443820).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like I hadn't searched hard enough.

I believe this post gives me the answer [Parsing TCL lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439124/parsing-tcl-lists-in-python)